# Maven - Pull code from SVN

Tags: svn, maven, compilation

I am migrating J2ee Project from Ant to Maven,
One of The ant tasks is to pull existing source from SVN Repository
Compile it, and add its jar to my current build as Jar

Is it possible to do the get the source and compile it in Maven?

Thank you!

```
<target name="checkoutBuild" description="Pulls code from SVN into the build directory">
    <exec executable="svn">
        <arg line="co ${svn.projecturl} ${project.build.root} -r ${svn.revision} --username ${svn.username} --password ${svn.password}"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in a similar way as in Ant. Execute the `svn` command in `exec-maven-plugin` in one of pre-compile phases, perhaps in *generate-sources*. I'd try something like this (it's a brain-dump, may contain minor mistakes):

```xml
<build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>svn</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <executable>svn</executable>
      <arguments>
        <argument>co</argument>
        <argument>${svn.projecturl}</argument>
        <argument>${project.build.root}</argument>
        ...
      </arguments>
    <configuration>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
```

**EDIT**

Prunge's answer made me think — what do you want to *really* achieve? If the project is always to be the part of the build, a far better way would be to "mavenize" it (write a POM for it) and include it as a module/dependency.

If the SVN checkout is to be a one-time action, maybe it's better to leave it as it is, add the jar to the repository with `mvn install:install-file` (assigning a group id and artifact id), and use it as a dependency?

Comment: **what do you want to really achieve** we are in the phase of development, 4 small java projects jar libs and one main Java project who uses these libs, all projects on the SVN.
I would like to check out the projects build them to one package,
Will it help if I "mavenize" the projects?

Comment: @user648026 The question is: is the life/release cycle of those project common with the main project? If so, "mavenize" them and **module-build** all together. If not, release them into repository and use as a **dependency** (of course, you can still write proper POM(s) for them).

Comment: Thank you for your time, about the lifecycle, all projects currently under Development, once you release the main project you release all related Jars,  say all projects have pom's and all the projects reside in SVN, what is the process of building a release?

Comment: @user648026 Building a release is exactly as user prunge answered. I'm not very proficient with Maven Release Plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can, but it is not the 'Maven Way' of doing things.

Take a look at the [Maven Release Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/) documentation.

What you'd typically do is:

- Define your [source control repository in your POM](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#SCM)
- Do a [release:prepare](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html) which verifies everything is OK (no SNAPSHOT dependencies for release, etc.)
- Do a [release:peform](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/perform-release.html).  You can do this to a clean empty directory or even on a different machine that doesn't have the project checked out (release:perform can check out sources from source control by specifying an SCM URI on the command line).

Comment: Release plugin is for committing build *output*. What the author wants to do is to fetch sources from the repository in the first place.

Comment: **>>>it is not the 'Maven Way' of doing things** -> This is the thing I am trying to understand - how to do this in Maven way? Say I have 2 developers working on two projects A,B both projects submitted to SVN, now I am project manager would like to release package for QA, how do I do that? Is the way you described in your answer will change? Thank you!