# How to include remote java sources with maven?

Tags: java, maven, thrift

I have a server project for which I want to provide a client library as **source** so that the depending project downloads, unpacks and compiles the client lib instead of using pre-compiled binaries. How can I do this with Maven 2?

I think I'm looking for something like the **maven-remote-resources-plugin** for Java source files.

The background is that I have serverA which exposes a thrift interface. ServerB can use the thrift file to generate the classes and use serverA. Now I want to distribute some helper classes for the generated thrift files without distributing the generated thrift files themselves. The reason for that is that we sometimes use different thrift versions between serverA and serverB which is no problem for the wire protocol but for conflicting classes on the classpath.

Comment: this could be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/q/7881437/1007273

Answer (score 0):

Never heard of such a case but i guess that including the dependency with the classifier `sources` should work.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>{groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>{artifactId}</artifactId>
        <version>{version}</version>
        <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

Then you could probably use the [Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-dependencies-mojo.html) with the goal `unpack-dependencies` to unpack the sources.